# Twig: Finding the sum of values of rows in column

Tags: sum, logic, twig

How do I find the total value of all the rows in a column with Twig? For example I have a column "QTY" that will list number of quantities of each row, I want the sum of the total ROWS of QTY (not the sum of qty). What is the tag/logic in Twig?

I have something like this:

```
<table class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
       <th>DA</th>
       <th>Part</th>
       <th>Batch</th>
       <th>Qty</th>
    </thead>
  {% for getbatches in getbatch %}
    <tr>
       <td>{{getbatch.dano}}</td>
       <td>{{getbatch.partno}}</td>
       <td class="highlight">{{getbatch.batchno}}</td>
       <td>{{getbatch.inqty}}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

For the rows that populate, I would like the count of the column of QTY, or any column.

Comment: Is it really the Twig 's job ?

Comment: What do you mean by "*sum of the total ROWS of QTY*"? Do you mean the count of rows in QTY column? Do you mean sum of the values inside each row of column QTY?

Comment: @Javad The count of rows in QTY column.

Comment: Could you put the code that how do you create the table in twig? That will be a good help to fix your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base on your code and according to that you want to get *Count of rows in Qty column* you can try

```
<table class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
     <th>DA</th>
     <th>Part</th>
     <th>Batch</th>
     <th>Qty</th>
  </thead>
  {% set row_count = 0 %}
  {% for getbatches in getbatch %}
  <tr>
     <td>{{getbatch.dano}}</td>
     <td>{{getbatch.partno}}</td>
     <td class="highlight">{{getbatch.batchno}}</td>
     <td>{{getbatch.inqty}}</td>
  </tr>
  {% set row_count = row_count + 1 %}
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

if you want to show that amount somewhere (like a span) you can use `<span>{{ row_count }}</span>` after

**UPDATED**

A better solution to show the rows count anywhere if your twig template might be just showing the count of `getbatches`:

```
<span>Row count: </span><span>{{ getbatches is defined ? getbatches|length : 0 }}</span>
```

Comment: It gave me an error that "row_count" does not exist in the template.

Comment: Where did you put the `row_count` in your code to show?

Comment: First I put it above the table and it gave me the error, but when I moved it below the table it still gave me the error.

Comment: @Noobtastic I have a better suggestion; that you can show the count of rows in anywhere; just updated my suggestion and you can see.

Answer (score 0):

If you print rows of a table in twig and wany to get the "count of rows in QTY column", you should pass this data to twig from doing a simple count() on the array of rows. If you want to do it "the hard way", you could do:

```
{% set numRows = 0 %}

{% for .... %}

{% set numRows = numRows + 1 %}

{% endfor %}
```

but as @TheLittlePig said, twig's purpose is to display data, not do calculations